# Stretch dynamic nested divs to fit fixed container?

Tags: css, size, containers, stretch, html

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a">dummy content</div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    height: 200px; /* Fixed height */
}

.a {
    height: auto; /* Dynamic height */
}

.b {
    height: 100%; /* I want this to fit inside .container, relative to .a */
}
```

When .a gets a dynamic height of for instance 100px, I want .b to be .container height - 100px. I want this to happen automatically, with pure CSS.

Please see my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/59MKS/.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this.

Comment: would you want to add some content in the class-b box?

Comment: @mayaa Yes, it should be able to contain some content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `float:left;` to class `.a`

Simple, but works.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work. I guess this would be the best solution?

Comment: It depends on what you need. Maybe you don't want `.b`'s content to overflow outside `.container` and then you can combine this solution with an `overflow:hidden` on `.container`. Just try out all solutions and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.container {
position: absolute;
background-color: red;
width: 100px;
height: 200px; /* Fixed height */
}

.a {
position: relative;
 background-color: green;
 width: 90px;
 height: auto; /* Dynamic height */
}

.b {   
background-color: blue;
 width: 80px;
   height: 100%; /* I want this to fit inside the red container */
}
```

Comment: My question might be a bit poorly worded. When .a gets a dynamic height of for instance 100px, I want .b to be .container height - 100px. I want this to happen automatically, with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use jQuery i guess. here's how i did it http://jsfiddle.net/59MKS/4/

```
var height = $(".container").height() - $(".a").height();

$(".b").css("height", height);
```